# Grant integrated security access rights for Microsoft SQL Server to LocalSystem account?

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication, web-applications, jdbc

Suppose my web application runs on a Windows server. It is hosted inside Tomcat, which runs as Windows service under the account [`LocalSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It accesses a Microsoft SQL Server on a remote Windows server. I would like to for the web application to authenticate to the SQL Server using integrated authentication.

From the answer to a previous question I know that the following sequence of SQL commands would enable integrated authentication if Tomcat were to run under the account `<your-domain-name>\A1`.

```
CREATE LOGIN [<your-domain-name>\A1] FROM WINDOWS;
CREATE USER [<your-domain-name>\A1];
GRANT ... ON <object-name> TO [<your-domain-name>\A1];
```

What is the correct SQL syntax for granting similar rights to the `Local System`account on host `H1`, if it can be done?

Comment: "LocalSystem" and "LOCAL SERVICE" are two very very distinct accounts.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I'm not a Windows guy (not the admin of the Tomcat box :) What does it tell me if Tomcat (evidently) runs as "LocalSystem", not "LOCAL SERVICE"?

Comment: You originally had the title referencing "Local Service". The answer would be very different for that case, as [LOCAL SERVICE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684188(v=vs.85).aspx) is not allowed to authenticate remotely and you would simply *not* be able to configure a login for it (short of granting ANONYMOUS LOGON a login, which is a huge no-no).

Comment: @RemusRusanu You are right. The title was off. Just checked on the Tomcat system. It says "Log on as: Local System" under Windows Services. Thx for editing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Local System` identifies as the computer account on the local network. The computer account is identified by the computer name with a `$` postfix.

So to create a login for the Local System account from host `H1` on domain `<your-domain-name>` you would need to run the following command:

```
CREATE LOGIN [<your-domain-name>\H1$] FROM WINDOWS;
```

After that you may run the following commands to grant authorization to this account:

```
CREATE USER [<your-domain-name>\H1$] FOR LOGIN [<your-domain-name>\H1$];
GRANT ... ON <object-name> TO [<your-domain-name>\H1$];
```